# Single linked list delete function with recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to make a students list for a project in c
the functions inside the program are 3
    insert = inserts students to the list
    print = prints out the students available
    delete = deletes a student from the list

I have created the program and it works fine using all three functions
and now I would like to make the same list using recursion. 
I have made the print function recursive and it is working
now I am trying to make the delete function work the same way
unfortunately I am failing to make it work
In the code below if you run it you will see that it works only if you do not attempt to delete the last node on the list and if you do not tell it to delete a node that it does not exists.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct tf *tp;
            struct tf{
            int am;
            double gr;
            tp next;
            };

        tp head, tail, temp, aux;

    void insert1 (tp *h, tp t);
    void print1(tp h);
    void delete1(tp *h,int da);



    int main()
    {
        char fry, fry2;
        int am;
        fry = 'a';
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;

        while (fry != 'q')
        {
            printf("\n character given is %c\n", fry);
            if (fry != 'q')
            {
                printf("new choice\n");
                fry = 'a';
                fflush(stdin);
                fry = getchar();
                getchar();
                if (fry == 'q')
                    printf("quit\n");
                if (fry == 'i')
                {
                    fry2 = fry;
                    printf(" insert new student number am\n");
                    insert1(&head,tail);
                    fry = fry2;
                }
                if (fry == 'd')
                    {printf(" delete \n");
                    printf(" am number of student to be deleted\n");
                    scanf("%d", &am);
                    delete1(&head,am);
                    }

                if (fry == 'p')
                {
                    printf("\n printing\n");
                    print1(head);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void insert1 (tp *h, tp t)
    {
        tp te, a;
        int da;
            te = (tp)malloc(sizeof(struct tf));
            printf(" am number for the new insert\n");
            scanf("%d", &da);
            getchar();
            te->am = da;
            te->next = NULL;
                printf("am number is %d",te->am);
                if ((*h != NULL) && (te->am < (*h)->am))
                {
                    te->next = *h;
                    *h = te;
                }

             if((*h != NULL) && ((*h)->next != NULL) && (te->am > (*h)->am))
             {
                 a=*h;
                 while((a->next != NULL) && (a->next->am < te->am))
                 {
                     a= a->next;
                 }
                 te->next = a->next;
                 a->next = te;
             }

             if((*h != NULL) && ((*h)->next == NULL) && (te->am > (*h)->am))
             {
                 (*h)->next = te;
             }

             if(*h == NULL)
             {
                 printf("\n head is null");
                 *h = te;
                 t = te;
             }
    }



    void print1(tp h)
    {
        tp a;
        a=h;
        if (a==NULL)
            return;
        printf("%d\n",a->am);
        print1(a->next);
    }




    void delete1(tp *h,int da)
    {
        tp a= *h,t= *h,temp = NULL;
        if ((*h) != NULL)
        {
            if ((*h)->am!=da)
            {
                if (a->next->am != da && a->next!=NULL)
                {
                    delete1(a->next,da);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (a->next==NULL)
                    {
                        printf("am not found\n");
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = a->next;
                        a->next = a->next->next;
                        free(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                a = (*h);
                (*h)= (*h)->next;
                free(a);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("empty list");
        }


    }
```

As you can see I want the delete function to delete the node by looking for the am number given,so it will first search the list to find if the am number is there or not.

If anyone can give me a tip on how to make the delete function to work I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on. This line:

```
if (a->next->am != da && a->next!=NULL) ...
```

should have the conditions swapped, otherwise you might access `a->next` withot verifying that it isn't `NULL` first. The auxiliary variable `a` and the other temporaries are confusing rather than helpful.

You pass the `head` to the `delete1` function as pointer to pointer, so that the head can be updated. But this doesn't affect only the head: This adds a level of indirection thoughout your iteration.

For your iterative calls, this means that you must pass the address of the pointer that stores the reference to the current node, `(*h)->next`. At the beginning, this is the address of the head. On subsequent iterations, this is the address of the `next` pointer of the previous node.

There's also no need to consider various cases. The code can be as simple as:

```
void delete1(tp *h, int da)
{
    if (*h != NULL) {
        if ((*h)->am == da) {
            tp next = (*h)->next;

            free(*h);
            *h = next;
            return;
        }

        delete1(&(*h)->next, da);
    }
}
```

The recursive call happens at the end of the function or it doesn't happen at all. This means that you can rewrite the code as a loop:

```
void delete1(tp *h, int da)
{
    while (*h != NULL) {
        if ((*h)->am == da) {
            tp next = (*h)->next;

            free(*h);
            *h = next;
            return;
        }

        h = &(*h)->next;
    }
}
```

This will save you some stack space on large lists. Your `insert1` function could also be cleaned up and simplified.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply
i am a begginer and i am learning from my mistakes
your code is very beutyful
i will try to simplify the insert too,thank you for your instructions :D